# Java chat application on GAE, trouble with write messages to file

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsf, java-ee-6

I have problem with my program in JSF on Google App Engine platform. I almost finished implement chat application in Java EE, when I read that class *FileOutputStream* isn't supported by GAE. 
By this class object I create file, to write inside it chat messages and by scirpt this file is loaded and refreshed on index.xhtml website.

I need help because I don't know which class can I replace *FileOutputStream* to finish this application. I found [example in Python](http://vimeo.com/8066901) so I know that this is possible, but how to implement it in Java?

I will be grateful for any help.

Below I paste piece of class ChatBean with *FileOutputSream* operations:

```
@Stateful
@ApplicationScoped
@ManagedBean(name="Chat")
public class ChatBean {

    private List<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String newUser;
    FileOutputStream chatHtmlBufferWriter;

    public ChatBean () throws IOException {
        ServletContext ctx = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
        String chatHtmlPath = ctx.getRealPath("/") + "chat";
        try {
            this.chatHtmlBufferWriter = new FileOutputStream(chatHtmlPath);  
            this.chatHtmlBufferWriter.write("Start chatu ąęć. <br />".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            this.chatHtmlBufferWriter.close();
            throw ex;
        }

        users.add("Admin");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void closeFileBuffor() throws Exception {
        this.chatHtmlBufferWriter.close();
    }

    public String addMessage(String msg) throws IOException {
        this.chatHtmlBufferWriter.write(msg.getBytes("UTF-8"));    
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("index.xhtml");
        return "index"; 
    } 
...
}
```

And script inside index.xhtml file:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
            <script>
                var currPos = 0;
                var loadChat = function() {
                    $("#chatForm\\:chatbox").load('chat');
                    currPos = $(".chat")[0].scrollHeight;
                    $(".chat").scrollTop(currPos);
                }
                var scrollChat = function() {
                    $("#chatForm\\:chatbox").load('chat');
                    $(".chat").scrollTop(currPos);
                }
                var currPos;

                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#chatForm\\:chatbox").load('chat', function(){
                        loadChat();
                    });
                    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
                        scrollChat();
                    }, 1000);
                    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });                    
                    $("#chatForm\\:chatbox").scroll(function() {
                        currPos = $(".chat").scrollTop();
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can't directly write to the File System (although you can read).

You will need to use one of the existing GAE storage APIs, such as the blobstore which has a [File like API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore). Other options are detailed on the [Storing Data page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/).

However, I'm not sure you're thinking about this correctly; you just want to create a GET method that returns the current messages and is called by your script. The messages will never be written to file at all. To begin with, you could just store the messages in memory. I suspect the tutorial you link to does the same.

(UPDATE: I originally said FileOutputStream was in the whitelist, but I was looking at `FilterOutputStream`. Oops.)

Comment: Thanks for answer I'll check it. Now I started to think about another way of this problem. Maybe is possible  to write messages to object and show it without use file?

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I'm suggesting. Implement a GET method for the "/messages" URL or such which should return the list of current messages. You then make an AJAX call to this URL from the script and it should insert the messages into the page.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how it should look. Could you post sample structure of source code for this solution?

Comment: Why don't you just look at the Python example and do something similar?